# Canceling Backgroundworker that was set using a lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, backgroundworker

I have a backgroundworker that has been created using a lambda as shown here:

```
BackgroundWorker fileCountWorker= new BackgroundWorker();
fileCountWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
fileCountWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((obj, e) => GetFileInfo(folder, subs));
fileCountWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler((obj, e) => UpdateCountInFolderListViewForItem(index));
fileCountWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I would like to be able to cancel the backgroundworker, and then know that it was canceled in the RunWorkerCompleted function using the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e.Canceled property.

So far I have been unable to figure out a way to pass a parameter to the RunWorkerCompleted function and still maintain the ability to access the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.

I tried adding a RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs parameter to the function called by RunWorkerCompleted, and then passing the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs like so:

```
fileCountWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler((obj, e) => UpdateCountInFolderListViewForItem(index, e));
```

But that didn't seem to work.

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit**:

Following comments below, I made the following changes:

I changed the DoWork Event as follows (adding the obj and e as parameters in the worker function):

```
fileCountWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((obj, e) => GetFileInfo(folder, subs,obj,e));
```

I then changed the RunWorkerCompleted function as follows (adding the obj and e as parameters in the RunWorkerCompleted function):

```
fileCountWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler((obj, e) => UpdateCountInFolderListViewForItem(index, obj, e));
```

From my UI Thread I call CancelAsync:

```
if (bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
   {
      bgw.CancelAsync();
   }
```

Then from within the backgroundworker I check for cancellationpending like:

```
BackgroundWorker bwAsync = sender as BackgroundWorker;
if (bwAsync.CancellationPending)
   {
      e.Cancel = true;
      return;
   }
```

The result is that when I cancel the backgroundworker, it does stop the worker function, but theRunWorkerCompletedEventArgs in the RunWorkerCompleted function ( UpdateCountInFolderListViewForItem) still has a Canceled property set to False, so the function can't tell that the worker was canceled.

So i'm still stuck on getting the RunWorkerCompleted function to know that the worker was canceled instead of completing normally.

Comment: Using backgroundworker with lambdas is really bad idea. Use Task<> (TPL) or async/await or at least BeginInvoke.

Comment: @Andrey Care to detail *why* lambdas are a really bad idea?

Comment: @PeterRitchie because lambda is small unit of work, and there are more suitable tools to run such things.

Comment: @Andrey A statement lambda can be many lines long (as many as you want, assuming you don't have a .cs file longer than the compiler will accept.  A lambda is just an anonymous method...

Comment: @Andrey thanks Andrey, I wasn't aware of Task<>(TPL), but following your tip, I found an article explaining it on codeproject, and I am studying up on that now.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that the BGW is already done by the time you try to cancel it.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought of that as well, but was able to rule it out.  I have the worker function enumerating the files in a bunch of subdirectories, and when the RunWorkerCompleted function runs, it reports the count.  In this case when I cancel the worker, the RunWorkerCompleted function reports back a partial file count, so I know that I am canceling it before it finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()`.

Your worker code needs to check `BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending` and stop what it's doing to "cancel"... But, your lambda isn't doing anything you can really cancel.

Normally what you'd do is something like this:

```
//...
fileCountWorker.DoWork += (obj, e) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 && fileCountWorker.CancellationPending; ++i)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);/* really do other work here */
    }
    e.Cancel = fileCountWorker.CancellationPending;
};

fileCountWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); 

//...

fileCountWorker.CancelAsync();
```

If you provide some details of `GetFileInfo`, maybe some more detail could be provided.

Comment: This just argument why BackgroundWorker+lamdas don't play well.

Comment: @Andrey Again, in what way?

Comment: @PeterRitchie The problem is that when I call fileCountWorker.CancelAnsync(); It does cancel the worker, and then calls the RunWorkerCompleted function, however, I am unable to tell within the RunWorkerCompleted function if the backgroundworker completed on its own, or was canceled (which I would test using the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.  The GetFileInfo is simply a function that is utilizing the DirectoryInfo for EnumerateFiles().  So if the RunWorkerCompleted function is also created using a lambda, can you still get the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs from the worker?

Comment: @Blau the `RunWorkerCompleted` will always be called, even if you cancel (see `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled`.  But to cancel, your code needs to check `CancellationPending`.  `CancelAsync` doesn't magically stop your code from running--your code must explicitly cancel.  RE event args:  Sure, the `e` in your lamba is the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` object

Comment: @PeterRitchie following your suggestions, I made some changes and posted it as an edit in the original post.  I still haven't got it figured out.

Comment: @Blau Sorry, I forgot the `DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel` property needs to be set to `true` when cancelling.  I've updated my example to just copy the `CancellationPending` value, but you may explicitly set it to `true`.